# Wi-Fi not working on home router after ICS update (Galaxy S2)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Can someone help me? I'm really frustrated now and eating through my data like theres no tomorrow. Since I did the ICS update I can't connect my samsung galaxy s2 to my home wireless router (belkin n1)! It says `obtaining ip address`...`authenticating`...`saved secured with wpa/wpa2 psk` and then repeats over and over again! But no Wi-Fi, and I cant get online etc...

Does anyone know what would cause this? How do I fix it?

Comment: How did you perform the update? via KIES or some other method? Check to ensure in the Wi-Fi settings you haven't specified a static IP address for your phone. And that your router isn't configured to disallow/allow certain IP addresses or MAC addresses.

Comment: ive forgot the network and done it manually and same thing occurs... i tryed wifi fixer app and still no joy

Answer (score 3):

What steps have you undertaken to resolve the problem?

Some suggestions:

- Try restarting the phone
- Try removing the network entry ("Forget Network"), then add it again. Please make sure that you have the necessary information to reconnect before doing this.

edit: [related Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22552/galaxy-s2-wifi-not-working-after-ics-update)

Comment: i done the update on work wifi then battery drained so i finished the update at a friends house! ive been told theres no need to set up a static ip! definatly something to do with settings on my belkin n1 router can someone please hase a look for me its driving me mad!!!

Comment: The way I understand your comment, the upgrade was interrupted?

Comment: yes well split if you like... because my battery drained i had to finish the update when i had a full charge. never had any problems with connecting to my home network before... i can connect to anything else but my own...it literally finds the network shows its connected saved etc but dosnt let me online :S ... its a belkin n1 wireless router and i really belioeve its something to do with the settings on it. i may try typing ip address into homebar and messing around with secuity changing to aes i think i got it on tkip at the min. someone also mentioned changing b+G+N setting to n only????